# Recompiling stored procedures result in error "function SHASH_HMAC is not defined. module name or entrypoint could not be found."

Tags: debian, user-defined-functions, firebird, firebird2.5

I want to migrate database to new server, and I have problem with stored procedures compilation. I have error like this:

> Invalid token.
> invalid request BLR at offset 588.
> function SHASH_HMAC is not defined.
> module name or entrypoint could not be found.
> Error while parsing procedure X_SYS_GET_USERINFO's BLR.

Server details:

Old server: Debian 8.11 (jessie)
New server: Debian 11 (bullseye)

Firebird have some UDF's which I moved (copy paste 1:1) to new location.

What can I do to find the problem?

I have around 7-10 similar errors.

I first installed Firebird on RedHat. I thought that was the problem, so I changed the distribution (I heard from DEV that the UDFs were compiled for the Debian distribution). That didn't produce any results.

I thought about the system libs. Maybe here's the problem?

PS I'm a system admin, not a developer.

Bitness:
OLD

```
Server version: LI-V2.5.7.27050 Firebird 2.5
Server implementation: Firebird/linux AMD64
```

NEW:

```
Server version: LI-V2.5.9.27139 Firebird 2.5
Server implementation: Firebird/linux AMD64
```

About lld:

NEW:

```
ldd /opt/firebird/UDF/fb_shash
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffed7be6000)
        libib_util.so => not found
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found<br>
```

OLD:

```
ldd /opt/firebird/UDF/fb_shash
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffda771f000)
        libib_util.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libib_util.so (0x00007f6682710000)
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f6682313000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f6682008000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6681d07000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f6681af1000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6681746000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6681542000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6682b15000)
```

PS2 My firebird is runned via xinet.d

Comment: Where did you put the files on the new install, and what is the setting of the firebird.conf `UdfAccess`?

Comment: Does new Firebird bitness matches old one? Did you check dependency of UDF libraries with 'ldd'? You also can use 'strace' or 'dltrace' utilities during UDF loading to see what is wrong.

Comment: MarkRotteveel
I putted into the same location 1:1 (/opt/firebird/UDF). 
Both servers has the same commented UdfAccess line. @user13964273
How to use strace with firebird ?

Comment: Firebird can be run with "-a" switch for "application mode". You can use strace with it according to strace manual. But dltrace would be better because it focus on the UDF library load instead of any file opening.

Comment: 'ldd' you had to use to the UDF library, not Firebird server.

Comment: You may want to consider asking on [firebird-support](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support) instead. That is probably a better venue for troubleshooting this than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @user13964273 i wrote difference between libs. It can be the problem ? How to link to get the same result as on the old server?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thats Firebird 2.5. It can't be servised by firebird-support probably.

Comment: @MarekOadmin firebird-support is the Firebird *community* helping each other, it is not some helpdesk from a company. Although Firebird 2.5 is end-of-life, it is not as if there will be no one in the community to give you some advice or help (hell, people still ask questions about Firebird 1.5). In any case, your question is simply not suitable for Stack Overflow, because the obvious solutions don't seem to apply, or there is some key detail missing, and troubleshooting in comments simply doesn't work well.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for error is clearly stated in your ldd listings:

```
libib_util.so => not found
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
```

Your new server miss two important libraries. First one is library provided in Firebird package. Perhaps, it wasn't installed properly and link wasn't created in a folder where loader can find it. Second one was part of libssl package on Jessie but Bullseye comes with libssl1.1 that broke your UDF.

Either recompile the UDF with modern libraries or search for backward-compatibility package.

Comment: I tried to copy libcrypto.so.1.0.0 from old server, but still error exists. How to recompile UDF? Is any other ways to resolve version compatibility ?